# Importing google fonts in GtkCss3?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I tried to import roboto from google fonts in css file:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
```

but when I run application I get this error:

```
gtk-css-provider-error-quark: css:1:0unknown @ rule (1)
```

I searched for it in documentation and on google but I only found that's possible to use @import but only for other css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported; GTK CSS is slightly different from web CSS. To use a particular font in a desktop application, you need to install it on your system. Then you can simply specify it like this:

```
font-family: Roboto;
```

On Ubuntu, for example, you can make your app depend on the `fonts-google` package which includes Roboto.

(Imagine what would happen if importing web fonts was allowed; your app would stop functioning when the user didn't have an internet connection!)